# jQuery Trigger Event multiple times in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I'll start with some context: I wrote a little typing app that displays text on the screen and tracks your wpm as you type using the keypress event. Out of boredom I wanted to play around with it a little bit and have a way that it would auto type after typing a hidden command (shortend kontra code using just the arrow keys). So I have a array of characters that I am iterating through and attempting to simulate the keypress event in my each loop as shown below.

```
$.each(_arrToCopy, function (index, value) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log(value);

          jQuery.event.trigger({ type: 'keypress', which: value.charCodeAt(0) });

          //typeIt(value);
        }, time);
        time += 500;
      });
```

The issue I'm having is it appears that my event is only triggering one time and then not triggering again. The setTimeout function was an early attempt to slow the loop down in case I was just processing things too quickly. After that didn't work I implemented a nearly pure javascript function (the typeIt()) function to fake the keyboard event. It is below.

```
function typeIt(character) {
  var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
  var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";
  console.log(String.fromCharCode(character.charCodeAt(0)) + ' ' + (character.charCodeAt(0)));

  keyboardEvent[initMethod](
                     "keypress", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
                      true, // bubbles
                      true, // cancelable
                      window, // viewArg: should be window
                      false, // ctrlKeyArg
                      false, // altKeyArg
                      false, // shiftKeyArg
                      false, // metaKeyArg
                      0, // keyCodeArg 
                      character.charCodeAt(0) // charCodeArgs 
  );
  document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
}
```

This also typed once, but it appears to be typing the wrong character. So I circled back to trying to make the jQuery trigger work and have gotten stuck on that. I can get it to type the first letter, but after that it appears to completely stop firing. I was wondering if there's potentially a way to reset the event trigger if it's only able to fire once in the loop without being reset, or if that's even the issue here.

If for the sake of more context you want to take a look at what this is going in, I have a mock up here (although what I'm actually working on is now a bit more refined c# app will a full backend): http://codepen.io/jiggawagga/pen/wBoaRY

Thanks in advance team stackoverflow

Comment: you have your event listener setup with `$(document).one`, [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) makes the event listener only ever used once, after that it is never called again until you set it up again. If you want it to be always used use `.on`

Comment: @PatrickEvans I changed it to .on() out of curiosity, there were a few issues. The first issue was the result was the same as before, the first letter typed correctly and nothing else happened. The second was the page totally locked up. And third, if I use on() instead of one() my original keypress event fires twice which is why I used one() in the original app. If you change it in Codepen then type, you'll see the issue there.

Comment: I don't see you trying to use a simulated keypress event in the codepen. But calling `trigger` triggers the event no matter how many times you call it, [here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tu4x5bv2/). So something you are doing in the other part of your code is either turning off the event listener or you are not calling `trigger` correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in simple `jQuery` click event. I did below and it worked fine. See if it solves your issue

```
jQuery(document).off().on('click', '.my-div', function(){
     // SOME EVENT GOES HERE
})
```

Refer http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thedole/9Lt0f1cu/) to try it out. The only thing I had to change to get it to work was changing this:

```
jQuery.event.trigger({ type: 'keypress', which: value.charCodeAt(0) });
```

to this:

```
$('#out').trigger({ type: 'keypress', which: value.charCodeAt(0)});
```

Basically triggering the event on the element that is to receive it. I'm not very well versed in jQuery so this might not be the solution you're after. But it worked for me.

The full js for the fiddle:

```
var _arrToCopy = Array.prototype.slice.call("lorem ipsum");
var time = 0;
$('#out').keypress(function(e){
    $(this).text($(this).text() + String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});

$.each(_arrToCopy, function (index, value) {
    setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(value);
    $('#out').trigger({ type: 'keypress', which: value.charCodeAt(0)});
  }, time);
  time += 500;
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<p id="out">
```